# Why does dev_appserver.py exit without throwing errors?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to run a simple python 2 server code with AppEngine and Datastore. When I run `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`, the program immediately exits (without an error) after the following outputs:

```
/home/username/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/google/auth/crypt/_cryptography_rsa.py:22: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  import cryptography.exceptions
INFO     2022-12-20 11:59:41,931 devappserver2.py:239] Using Cloud Datastore Emulator.
We are gradually rolling out the emulator as the default datastore implementation of dev_appserver.
If broken, you can temporarily disable it by --support_datastore_emulator=False
Read the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator

INFO     2022-12-20 11:59:41,936 devappserver2.py:316] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2022-12-20 11:59:42,332 datastore_emulator.py:156] Starting Cloud Datastore emulator at: http://localhost:22325
INFO     2022-12-20 11:59:42,981 datastore_emulator.py:162] Cloud Datastore emulator responded after 0.648865 seconds
INFO     2022-12-20 11:59:42,982 <string>:384] Starting API server at: http://localhost:38915
```

Ideally, it should have continued by runnning the server on port 8000. Also, it works with option `--support_datastore_emulator=False`.

This is the code:

```
import webapp2
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db, deferred, ndb
import uuid
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode
import logging


class Email(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty()

class DB(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            mail = Email()
            mail.email = 'Test'
            mail.put()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            return self.response.out.write(e)
    
    def get(self):
        try:
            e1 = Email.query()
            logging.critical('count is: %s' % e1.count)
            e1k = e1.get(keys_only=True)
            logging.critical('count 2 is: %s' % e1k.count)
            e1 = e1.get()

            key = unicode(e1.key.urlsafe())
            logging.critical('This is a critical message: %s' % key)
            logging.critical('This is a critical message: %s' % e1k)

            e2 = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key).get()

            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            return self.response.out.write(str(e2.email))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            return self.response.out.write(e)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', DB)
], debug=True)
```

How can I find the reason this is not working?

Edit: I figured that the dev server works and writes to a datastore even with `support_datastore_emulator=False` option. I am confused by this option. I also don't know where the database is stored currently.

Comment: You have to include your code (at least the part that needs to be run when your program starts). You can also strip your code down to just a basic 'hello world' app and confirm you can start it, then gradually add back your code/imports to see where it errors out

Comment: I didn't include the code because it was very close to a hello world app. I am including the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It should be `count()` and not `count` i.e.

   `logging.critical('count is: %s' % e1.count())`
2. A `get` returns only 1 record and so it doesn't make sense to do a count after calling a `get`. Besides, the `count` operation is a method of the query instance not the results. This means the following code is incorrect

   ```
   e1k = e1.get(keys_only=True)
   logging.critical('count 2 is: %s' % e1k.count)
   ```

   You should replace it with

   ```
   elk = e1.fetch(keys_only=True) # fetch gives an array
   logging.critical('count 2 is: %s' % len(e1k))
   ```
3. When you first run your App, it will execute the GET part of your code and because this is the first time your App is being run, you have no record in Datastore. This means `e1 = e1.get()` will return None and `key = unicode(e1.key.urlsafe())` will lead to an error.

   You have to modify your code to first check you have a value for `e1` or `e2` before you attempt to use  the keys.
4. I ran your code with dev_appserver.py and it displayed these errors for me in the logs. But I ran it with an older version of gcloud SDK (Google Cloud SDK 367.0.0). I don't know why yours exited without displaying any errors. Maybe it's due to the version...??
5. Separately - Don't know why you're importing `db`. Google moved on to `ndb` long ago and you don't use `db` in your code
6. The default datastore (for the older generation runtimes like Python 2) is in `.config (hidden folder) > gcloud > emulators > datastore`

   You can also specify your own location by using the flag `--datastore_path`. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command)